# Testing Upload scalar type apollo-graphql in playground or Postman

Tags: http, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a mutation that has the `Upload scalar` (apollo-server v2 provides it) type as an argument.
Ex:

`type Mutation {
uploadImage(file:Upload):Boolean
}`

I want to test that mutation using `apollo playground` or Postman. So how to put a file in there?